# NullReferenceException on ShowDialog

Tags: wpf, prism

I'm new on WPF develpment with Prism Framework. I've watched some Brian's videos to learn about this two arguments.
Now I'm developing an app but I've an issue when I try to open a custom window dialog before the main window.
This is my simple window to open:

```
<Window x:Class="Dinamo.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Dinamo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox>WINDOW</TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the class into `xaml.cs`

```
public partial class Window1 : Window, IDialogWindow
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public IDialogResult Result { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
```

This is my shell class:

```
public partial class App
    {
        protected override Window CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {    
            base.OnStartup(e);
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterDialogWindow<Window1>();
        }
    }
```

and the MainWindowViewModel

```
public MainWindowViewModel(IDialogService dialogService)
        {
            dialogService.ShowDialog("Window1", null, null);
        }
```

But when I try this code I receive the error: `'A dialog's content must be a FrameworkElement'`

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: RTM read the manual: https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/dialogs/dialog-service.html ;)

Comment: But this manual is for Xamarin-form, not WPF. I've read that of WPF but the example of custom window isn't clear

Comment: Try now with the v8 release. You followed the docs to the letter, but the name parameter did not appear to exist in Core(?). I was having the same issue until v8.

Comment: Scratch that; still does not work as documented for core/unity.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the window is the fourth parameter. The first one is supposed to be a `UserControl` that defines the content of the dialog window:

```
dialogService.ShowDialog("UserControl1", null, null, "Window1");
```

You'll find an example [here](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/dialogs/dialog-service.html).

Comment: But I don't understand.. I've follow the documentation at this point https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/dialog-service.html#register-a-custom-dialog-window

Brian don't use a UserControl but a Infragistic ribbon window.

Comment: @Lic: It says "*in order to use a dialog window by name, you must provide the dialog window name in the IDialogService.Show or IDialogService.ShowDialog method as follows*" and then it's an example of how to call the `ShowDialog` similar to the one I provided in my answer. What's your point? If you don't believe me, you could take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/3ab9483145e383d85f69a8660835de4a7da80cdf/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Services/Dialogs/DialogService.cs) yourself.

Comment: No, I believe in you. I'm trying to understand.
But in my case, what I should write on first parameter?

Comment: @Lic: I guess you should put the `Grid` with the `TextBlock` in a `UserControl` and simply define the window as a standalone class without any .xaml file.